# Why is my code erroring with the return statement "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'connections"?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I've been troubleshooting with the NEAT add-on in Python and ran into another issue. When I tried to run my code, I got an error pertaining to this part specifically to the bolded line. I don't see any other errors in my code; looking at other examples, they seem to be implemented similarly.

```
def evaluate_genome(genome, config):
   ** net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)**
    melody = []
    for _ in range(num_measures * beats_per_measure):
        inputs = [random.random()]
        output = net.activate(inputs)
        note = int(output[0] * 127)
        melody.append(note)
    fitness = calculate_fitness(melody)
    return fitness
```

This should have run fully, and I was expecting it to at least run through all of my generations. For reference, here is the entire code and my config file is linked below:

```
import neat
import random
import numpy as np
import os
from midiutil import MIDIFile

config_path = "config.txt"
num_generations = 10
num_measures = 16
beats_per_measure = 4
num_tracks = 1
beat_duration = 0.25


output_file = "generated_music.mid"


def evaluate_genome(genome, config):
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome, config)
    melody = []
    for _ in range(num_measures * beats_per_measure):
        inputs = [random.random()]
        output = net.activate(inputs)
        note = int(output[0] * 127)
        melody.append(note)
    fitness = calculate_fitness(melody)
    return fitness


def calculate_fitness(melody):
    melodic_fitness = calculate_melodic_fitness(melody)
    harmonic_fitness = calculate_harmonic_fitness(melody)
    rhythmic_fitness = calculate_rhythmic_fitness(melody)
    overall_fitness = melodic_fitness + harmonic_fitness + rhythmic_fitness
    return overall_fitness


def calculate_melodic_fitness(melody):
    melodic_fitness = 0.0  # Placeholder value
    return melodic_fitness


def calculate_harmonic_fitness(melody):
    harmonic_fitness = 0.0
    return harmonic_fitness


def calculate_rhythmic_fitness(melody):
    rhythmic_fitness = 0.0  # Placeholder value

    return rhythmic_fitness


def run_neat():
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config.txt")
    config = neat.Config(
        neat.DefaultGenome,
        neat.DefaultReproduction,
        neat.DefaultSpeciesSet,
        neat.DefaultStagnation,
        config_path,
    )
    population = neat.Population(config)
    reporter = neat.StdOutReporter(True)
    population.add_reporter(reporter)

    winner = population.run(evaluate_genome, num_generations)

    best_genome = winner
    best_net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(best_genome, config)

    melody = []
    for _ in range(num_measures * beats_per_measure):
        inputs = [random.random()]
        output = best_net.activate(inputs)
        note = int(output[0] * 127)
        melody.append(note)

    midi_file = MIDIFile(num_tracks)
    track = 0
    time = 0
    for note in melody:
        midi_file.addNote(track, 0, note, time, beat_duration, 100)
        time += beat_duration

    with open(output_file, "wb") as file:
        midi_file.writeFile(file)

    print("Generated music saved as", output_file)


run_neat()
```

```
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 400
pop_size              = 50
reset_on_extinction   = False

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 20
species_elitism      = 2

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 2
survival_threshold = 0.2

[DefaultGenome]
# node activation options
activation_default      = relu
activation_mutate_rate  = 1.0
activation_options      = relu

# node aggregation options
aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.0
aggregation_options     = sum

# node bias options
bias_init_mean          = 3.0
bias_init_stdev         = 1.0
bias_max_value          = 30.0
bias_min_value          = -30.0
bias_mutate_power       = 0.5
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.7
bias_replace_rate       = 0.1

# genome compatibility options
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.0
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.5

# connection add/remove rates
conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.5

# connection enable options
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.01

feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full_direct

# node add/remove rates
node_add_prob           = 0.2
node_delete_prob        = 0.2

# network parameters
num_hidden              = 1
num_inputs              = 1
num_outputs             = 1

# node response options
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.0
response_max_value      = 30.0
response_min_value      = -30.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.0
response_mutate_rate    = 0.0
response_replace_rate   = 0.0

# connection weight options
weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 1.0
weight_max_value        = 30
weight_min_value        = -30
weight_mutate_power     = 0.5
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.1

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't initialize the tuples. Changed the code to initialize them as having a fitness of zero